# Static Variables Not Affecting Other Objects in Java Calendar Class

Tags: java, date, object, static, calendar

Since the `Calendar` class in Java has static data fields such as `DATE`, why don't the other objects change when the static field is modified?
I have made two different Gregorian Calendars and thought static data fields changed the value for all of the objects instead of one.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

        GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();

        cal2.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);

        System.out.println(cal2.get(Calendar.DATE));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));

     }
}
```

Comment: `Calender.DATE` is also `final` and can not be changed. It is just used to indicate to `set` that the date of `cal2` should be changed.

Comment: Please use more care and effort in writing your Question and its title. The title should narrowly describe the core issue at hand. Also, what are you attempting to do with the call to `set` passing `45`?

Comment: I had just made the account and am getting used to the whole asking questions issue sorry about that. And nothing really I just threw a random number in without even thinking of it, I just wanted to set the calendar date to something else. @BasilBourque

Comment: @Oswald  No apologies needed. Just hit the "Edit" link/button and fix the title and 45. The Questions and Answers are meant to be kept around for posterity, so please do fix it up. Stack Overflow is more like Wikipedia than a transient mailing list discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Calendar.DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE) is not a static field, it's a static variable that's used to reference which type of value you want to set/get in a specific `Calendar` instance.

If you look at the [actual source code of `java.util.Calendar`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/hs-dev/jdk/file/3eb4e20b34cb/src/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java) you would see that it has an internal `int` array that holds all the values, i.e. day, month, year, etc.

`Calendar.DATE` is just a nice way of referencing the fifth element of that array.

---

Declaration of member in the Java 8 source code.

```
/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DAY_OF_MONTH</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DAY_OF_MONTH
 */
public final static int DATE = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by rorschach is correct and should be accepted.

Also, you are using old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. They have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
LocalDate nextWeek = today.plusWeeks( 1 );
LocalDate midMonth = today.withDayOfMonth( 15 );
LocalDate firstOfMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() );
LocalDate secondTuesdayOfThisMonth = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( 2 , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) );
```